# How to move specific cells in a row from one worksheet to another based on Month in Month Due column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, pivot-table

I have been googling for a while trying to find a solution for how to copy specific cells in a row from one sheet to another. I have only been finding ways to copy entire rows. I have a workbook and the column names in the main sheet are:

**ID | Document Name | Purpose |Group | Priority | Month Due | Owner | Due Date | Completed On Time |Location**

The column names in the Jan, Feb, March, etc sheets are:

**ID | Document Name | Owner | Back-Up | Due Date | Approval Date | Completed Date | Location | New Document Name | Notes**

I only want the

**ID | Document Name | Owner | Due Date | Location**

to transfer to the corresponding columns of the worksheet that corresponds with the month in the Month Due section. So like if the Month Due column in the main worksheet has March selected, I want it to go into the Mar worksheet.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Can you please attach some sample screenshots so that we can see what you exactly want.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and be specific about the issue,, like is there any criteria to copy data from one to another sheet,, also for better understanding post some sample data or share workbook on Cloud/Dropbox.